# Links works in Browser but don't work in iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, ipad

I am working on a website which supports swipe gestures. Within each slide, I have few links which user can click and browse to different locations. The problem, and very weird one is, that my links are not working in iPad. They work perfectly in browsers.

I checked all Z-Index, etc and even put in absolute position but to no avail. My CSS and HTML is posted but instead of copying this, I'd recommend if you could see the framework I am using, you can go to [dragend](http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/) and open this site in iPad. Now click on link and you'll be surprised that the links on this site wouldn't work in iPad but would work on normal browsers.

### CSS

```
#contend {
  border-top: 13rem solid transparent;
  /*border-bottom: 4rem solid transparent;*/

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#swipe-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;


  cursor: hand;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.confine {
  max-width: 100%;
} 

#swipe-container .page-content {
  padding: 2rem 6rem;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#swipe-container .page-content:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#swipe-container p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.page-content p,.page-content ul,h3 {
  background: rgba(242,242,242,0.4);

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(242,242,242,0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(242,242,242,0.4);
}

#swipe-container > div > ul ul {
  margin: 0 0 2rem 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
}

#swipe-container > div {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(../imgs/bgbg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#swipe-container > div > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

#swipe-container li {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent !important;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent !important;
}

#pos2{
    position:fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;

    background-color: yellow;
}
#pos1:hover, #pos2:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

### HTML

```
 <div id="contend">
    <div id="swipe-container">
      <ul id="pages">
       <!-- meet the team-->

        <li class="page">
          <div class="page-content">

              <div class="link-slide-team">
                  <a href="cnn.com"> <div id="pos1"></div></a>
                  <a> <div id="pos2"></div></a>
              </div>

          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect they are using a `.preventDefault()` in the script for touch devices to disable native scrolling ect. Try listening for click manually and see if it fires.

Comment: add http:// to your links

Comment: Thanks guys, but it didn't work. If preventDefault was the problem, it'd have been the same in Desktop version, but it works fine on normal browsers and not in iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<a href="cnn.com">` to `<a href="http://www.cnn.com">`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. It's something more than that. Were you able to visit the dragend site, it shows the problem clearly.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately I don't have an iPad here to test